# PYTHON : How to create columns from words occurred in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe for example like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 
                      'col2':['foo bar', 'bar', 'something foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']})
```

I want to generate columns for each word appearing in one of the columns,e.g., col2 and count the number of its occurrences in that row.

```
  col1   col2          foo bar something 
0    A  foo bar         1   1    0
1    B  bar             0   1    0
2    C  something foo   1   0    1
3    A  foo             1   0    0
4    A  bar             0   1    0
5    B  foo             1   0    0
```

my dataframe is much bigger than this examples with more words. Each column can have more than one word.

Answer (score 5):

You need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) + [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df = my_df.join(pd.get_dummies(my_df['col2']))
print (df)
  col1       col2  bar  foo  something
0    A        foo    0    1          0
1    B        bar    1    0          0
2    C  something    0    0          1
3    A        foo    0    1          0
4    A        bar    1    0          0
5    B        foo    0    1          0
```

EDIT - is necessary [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
df = my_df.join(my_df['col2'].str.get_dummies(' '))
print (df)
  col1           col2  bar  foo  something
0    A        foo bar    1    1          0
1    B            bar    1    0          0
2    C  something foo    0    1          1
3    A            foo    0    1          0
4    A            bar    1    0          0
5    B            foo    0    1          0
```

But if multiple same words in one row and need count them:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 
                      'col2':['foo bar foo', 'bar', 'something foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo']})
print (my_df)
  col1           col2
0    A    foo bar foo
1    B            bar
2    C  something foo
3    A            foo
4    A            bar
5    B            foo

df = my_df.join(my_df['col2'].str.split(expand=True)
                             .apply(pd.value_counts,1)
                             .fillna(0)
                             .astype(int))
print (df)
  col1           col2  bar  foo  something
0    A    foo bar foo    1    2          0
1    B            bar    1    0          0
2    C  something foo    0    1          1
3    A            foo    0    1          0
4    A            bar    1    0          0
5    B            foo    0    1          0
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use `get_dummies` and `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([my_df,my_df.col2.str.get_dummies(' ')],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  col1           col2  bar  foo  something
0    A        foo bar    1    1          0
1    B            bar    1    0          0
2    C  something foo    0    1          1
3    A            foo    0    1          0
4    A            bar    1    0          0
5    B            foo    0    1          0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a memory saving solution for huge data sets, which is using sparse matrix and SparseDataFrame:

```
In [33]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [34]: vect = CountVectorizer()

In [35]: X = vect.fit_transform(my_df['col2'])

In [36]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(),
                                index=my_df.index, default_fill_value=0)

In [37]: r['col1'] = my_df.col1

In [38]: r
Out[38]:
   bar  foo  something col1
0    1    1          0    A
1    1    0          0    B
2    0    1          1    C
3    0    1          0    A
4    1    0          0    A
5    0    1          0    B
```

Pay attention at memory usage:

```
In [39]: r.memory_usage()
Out[39]:
Index        80
bar          24  # 3 * 8 byte (np.int64)
foo          32  # 4 * 8 byte (np.int64)
something     8  # 1 * 8 byte (np.int64)
col1         48
dtype: int64
```

NOTE: this will work only for Pandas versions 0.20.1+. For earlier versions we can use the following trick:

```
for i, col in enumerate(vect.get_feature_names()):
    my_df[col] = pd.SparseSeries(X[:, i].A.ravel(), fill_value=0)
```

instead of:

```
r = pd.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(),
                       index=my_df.index, default_fill_value=0)
```